# how to change network adapter in VMWare Workstation 12 on Windows?

Tags: vmware-workstation, network-adapter, rename

Can we change the network adapter name as mentioned in the screenshot on VMWare Workstation 12?

[image]

I would like to change it for easier managing and configuring the system.
Please let me know if anyone have done it before.

Thanks in advance.